# Cast application's visible content to Chromecast

Tags: ios, google-cast

I would like to cast my application's screen to Chromecast using the Chromecast iOS SDK provided by Google.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Currently I see the following possibility :

I "create a mini-server on the phone to serve them from. Then just tell your receiver (probably the Styled one), to access the local server (on your iPhone)."

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Thanks for any answer in advance!

UPDATE :

Now I am here

```
I have an application that is capturing video camera input and streaming it into mp4

I have an another application that is passing the first application's URL to a Chromecast device using this code

GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation = [[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:@"rtsp://192.168.5.159" streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeLive contentType:@"video/mp4" metadata:metadata streamDuration:0 customData:nil];
//cast video [_mediaControlChannel loadMedia:mediaInformation autoplay:TRUE playPosition:0];
```

The Chromecast device tries to play the stream but immediately fails.

Can you give any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Currently that is how you would do it.

Comment: I am neither criticizing, nor asking for more info since I am simply saying what the original poster has done is the way to do it right now, that is a perfectly valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a web server on your iDevice.
2. Capture your app's screen and save it in the web server location.
3. Send command to your cast receiver to include the URL to the captured image.

(Will need to use custom receiver)